# Wrong Coordinates when clicking on the map with Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm using **Openlayers 3** and I am getting a wrong coordinates out from the `ol.MapBrowserPointerEvent`. 
The point is, I get this coordinates, I print a popup (with `popup.show`) and it is meters away from the place I clicked on. However, when I get a geometry (point) from `PostGIS` to print it with the same method (`popup.show`), it's correctly placed.
I did all the checks to be positive on this (veryfied it manually with `QGIS` and the same raster layer as a reference).
Hence I assume the coordinates I get from the click event are not correct...(or not in the proper projection)

```
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:25830');

map = new ol.Map({
 layers: [
  new ol.layer.Group({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom: false}).extend([
        new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom({
          constrainResolution: true
        })
      ]),
  layers:[ basemap, mapbox]
  }),new ol.layer.Group({
    layers: [ orto, pks, medidas, video_milestones]}) ,],
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: ({
    collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [ 686776,4223752 ],
    zoom: 15,
    projection: projection,
    minZoom: 5,//minimo zoom que el usuario puede hacer
    maxZoom: 23 //maximo zoom que el usuario puede hacer
   })
 });
 popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
 map.addOverlay(popup);
```

This is the click event handler:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var str = '<div><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></div>'
    popup.show(evt.coordinate,str);
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Coordinates I get in evt.coordinates do not match the actual position I clicked on! I know that since I raise a popup in those corrdinates and they are meters away from the place I clicked at

Comment: The question is, why the coordinates in evt.coordinates are different from the ones I click on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had a zoom set in the body style within a CSS file, it changed the coordinates value